# How to store variable value in associative array key

Tags: bash, variables, associative-array

I would like to know how I could possible store a variables value into a key.

So that when the key is accessed it will output the key + variables value.

When I create a associative array and insert a variable into and echo the key it outputs the variables name rather than the variables value. How do I get bash' interpreter to parse this correctly?

Tried 
    "${varaible}"
    ${variable}
    "$variable"
    $variable

```
variable="some string"

declare -A array
array=(
['some code ${variable}']="keyvalue"
['${variable} some more code']="keyvalue2"
['and even some more code ${variable}']="keyvalue3"
)
for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    key=$i
    value=${array[$i]}
    echo "$key : $value"
done
```

The code outputs:

```
and even some more code ${variable} : keyvalue3
```

I'm trying to achieve this output:

```
and even some more code some string : keyvalue3
```

Comment: Single quotes don't expand variables, double quotes do.

Comment: considered evil by many, try `eval echo "$key : $value"`. It can be dangerous if you don't have control over what is setting the value for `${variable}`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash


variable="some string"

declare -A array

array['foo']="keyvalue"
array['bar']="keyvalue2"
array[$variable]="keyvalue3"

for i in "${!array[@]}"
do
    key=$i
    value=${array[$i]}
    echo "$key : $value"
done
```

Comment: The problem in the question is the use of variables within single quotes, though.

Comment: Yes I need it to output the variable's value within the single quotes of the keys.

Comment: @JakeLeroy You cannot output the variable's value within the single quotes because within single quotes $ sign is not interpreted as variable substitution but as  literal '$'.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg so using two arrays may be the most effective option?

Comment: @JakeLeroy Not sure why do you need single quotes. But in your example replacing single quotes to double quotes will lead to the desired result.

some more code : keyvalue2
and even some more code  : keyvalue3
some code  : keyvalue

I see no need to have two arrays.
Please note that single quote is used for NOT to substitute variable value in string that starts with $

Comment: You're correct but how do I add \n to the keys? it seems to just print the keys with "\n" in them.

Comment: @Jake edit your question to show a better example of whatever the problem is you're having and include this `\n` issue you're now talking about.

Comment: @JakeLeroy `\n` is sometimes used to represent the (nonprinting) newline character, but it is not the newline character itself. In some situations, `\n` will be *translated* into a newline; if you want a newline, you have to use `\n` in such a way that it gets translated.

Comment: Yes I want to use newline inside the keys.

Comment: Try `array[$'foo\nbar']=17; for i in "${!array[@]}"; do printf '<%s>\n' "$i"; done`